# How can I change the size of appendix in the document

Tags: formatting, overleaf, appendix

**Dear everyone:**

**I would like to change the size of the title of appendix in the article.**

**I use the following packages：**

```
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{titlesec}
```

**I use the following code to add the appendix**

```
\begin{appendices}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
\makeatletter
\addtocontents{toc}{%
  \begingroup
  \let\protect\l@chapter\protect\l@section
  \let\protect\l@section\protect\l@subsection
}
\makeatother
  \chapter{First appendix}
  \section{First section}
  \section{Second section}

  \chapter{Second appendix}
  \section{First section}
  \section{Second section}
\addtocontents{toc}{\endgroup}
\end{appendices}
```

**Other setting information is**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{arxiv}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % allow utf-8 input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8-bit T1 fonts
\usepackage{hyperref}       % hyperlinks
\usepackage{url}            % simple URL typesetting
\usepackage{booktabs}       % professional-quality tables
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % blackboard math symbols
\usepackage{nicefrac}       % compact symbols for 1/2, etc.
\usepackage{microtype}      % microtypography
\usepackage{lipsum}     % Can be removed after putting your text content
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{doi}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\title{Can the machine learn from the past of the funds or the fund manager information?}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}

\usepackage{array}

\newenvironment{conditions}
  {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} l}}
  {\end{tabular}\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}
```

**However, the size of the appendix section is bigger than the other section.(e.g the title of reference section)**

[image]

**If you know any method that can help me to solve this issue, I will be really grateful.**
**Thank you for your help**

**Best wishes**

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The `article` document class doesn't support the `\chapter` directlive natively. You should either switch to a document class that does support `\chapter` or switch the `\chapter` directives in the appendix to `\section`, `\section` to `\subsection`, etc.

Comment: @Mico Thank you for the help~! I will check the setting of the \chapter